# How to set variable value in Node.js to get request's the body data

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie in Node.js. I want to store the value of body.xyz in variable A. and want to access from the outside the request like i did in at end of the code. Here is my code, How I can set the variable value. It is showing null value at the end of program.

```
var request = require('request');

URL = "http://aaaa.com/api.php"


// Decleare the variables
var A = null;

PARAMS_0 = {
    'a':"query"
}

request.get( {
    url: URL, 
    qs: PARAMS_0
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
        body = JSON.parse( body)
        A = body.xyz 
    }
);
console.log( A )
```

Comment: Remember that node.js is asynchronous. You are making request and giving it a callback. It means that console.log(A) executes **before** getting your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing null because callback from `request.get` is executed after `console.log`, if you would add `console.log` inside of callback you would see the result.

Install https://github.com/request/request-promise

Try this one:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

URL = "http://aaaa.com/api.php"

PARAMS_0 = {
    'a':"query"
}

(async () => {
const A = await request.get( {
    url: URL, 
    qs: PARAMS_0
    });
console.log( A );
})();
```

Read this article: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261

It perfectly explains idea of promises, and how you should work with them.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to put Console.log statement inside the callback, if you are not getting the output.
Bacause node's asynchronous behaviour makes it possible that a statement written after another statement will get executed / produce output first that is what i think is happenning with your case.

Hope it helped.